# Select range of rows BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I know this is a trivial question but i was unable to find an answer. I want to select rows from 1000 to 2000 in my BQ table and I don't know how to to it.
I am looking for a function in BQ that would substitute python's **df.loc[1000:2000]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select * from your_table order by reasonable_column limit 1000 offset 1000` doesn't work for you? ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_clause_and_offset_clause))

UPDATE: added `order by` clause, thanks Martin for comment

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY` just to be safe. BQ doesn't guarantee any order in tables